# how to have two objects javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I Have Code:

```
function webdata(){
  this.page = function(e){
    return document.querySelectorAll(e);
    this.append = function(t){
      e.innerHTML += t;
    }
  };
}

var wb = new webdata();
```

when ever I call : `wb.page("html").append("Text");`

I get : `TypeError: wb.page(...).append is not a function`

I need a way of having an object inside of an object like jQuery. e.g. `$("html").append("Text");`

Comment: jQuery uses chaining concept, check this [link](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html)

Comment: Well you return the html collection, and the code after it is never run. And after that, `e` is a string and a string does not have innerHTML. You would need to return an object that has your method.

Comment: Move `this.append = function(t){
      e.innerHTML += t;
    }` to outside this.page. Then it will run without error. Can't guarantee the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of mistakes

1. `return document.querySelectorAll(e);` is returning `NodeList` to page function where `NodeList` don't have `append` method
2. `this.append` will never get called

You can modify the code as below which can work

```
function webdata(){
  this.page = function(e){
    e = document.querySelectorAll(e); // Get All Nodes
    this.append = function(t){
      e.forEach(function(elm){ // Perform operation on each node and append text to that node 
       elm.innerHTML += t; 
      });
      return this;  // Provide chaining for next nodes .append('abc').append('pqr')
    }
    return this; // .page('div').append will be availabel
  };
}

var wb = new webdata();
//Now this will work
wb.page(".question-hyperlink").append('abc').append('pqr');
```

Comment: I Get an error `TypeError: e.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I have tested on Chrome 52.0.2743.116 , working fine

Comment: Im using firefox v. 48.0.2